# PHP - Prevent accees for unregistered users

Tags: php

I'm building a simple site as a homework. It requires login to see the content but right now if i go to myserver/welcomepage.php I can see the content. I used the following code to my welcomepage:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
     header('Location:index.php');
     exit;
}
```

but if someone try to login with false login and then goes again in myserver/welcomepage.php he can see the content.
I read about using the IP or cookies.
What do you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend to check the authentication flow. It seems to me that your application will set the `$_SESSION['Username']` even if the login fails.

Comment: Yeah, this was an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `$_SESSION['Username']` on failed login. Check the function where your login is handled and only set the session variable if the users login was successful. Also make sure you are including `session_start();` at the very top and that that code snippet appears before ANY html including the `<html>` tag. header will only work if it comes before any output is sent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean does the session way secure my application page or it is easy to bypass?

Comment: Session will secure your page as long as your login is secure. A system is only as secure as its weakest point. Just make sure your login page doesn't have any vulnerabilities left open such as being able to SQL inject it and that you only assign a session to someone who successfully logs in. Don't set a session to a user if the login fails. And if you really wanna beef it up a little you can always throttle the logins so it can't be brute forced or add a captcha to it. And hash and salt the passwords so they aren't left as plain text in the database.